# How to combine two csv files to create one JSON object with specific header names with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I currently have two csv tables.  One is for **Pharmaceuticals** and the other is for **Nutraceuticals**:
here is **Pharmaceuticals**

```
                  Drug  Percentile
0     SZ Antipsychotic          57
1              AMG 811          57
2           Colchicine          57
3            Ibuprofen          29
4    Sleep Deprivation          29
5            Rofecoxib          29
```

and here is **Nutraceuticals**

```
                                             Drug  Percentile
0                                          Canova          57
1                             Omega-3 fatty acids          43
2                                        Luteolin          29
3   Ethanol Extract of Aurantiochytrium sp. (EEA)          14
4                                         Osthole          14
5                 Arisaema amurense var. serratum          14
```

I basically need to combine these two csv files into one JSON object such that each table is an array of dictionaries paired with their respective label.  The **expected output** is this (the names are different, only structure is important here):

```
{
"nutraceuticals": [
        {
            "name": "Omega-3 fatty acids",
            "percentile": 38
        },
        {
            "name": "Luteolin",
            "percentile": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Vitamin D",
            "percentile": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Probiotics supplements",
            "percentile": 13
        }
    ],
    "pharmaceuticals": [
        {
            "name": "Dexamethasone",
            "percentile": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Rofecoxib",
            "percentile": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Ibuprofen",
            "percentile": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Laquinimod",
            "percentile": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Lumiliximab",
            "percentile": 25
        }
   ]
}
```

I currently have this code:

```
result = Drug_Scoring.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    parsed = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
```

which produces the correct format in dictionary code, here:

```
[
    {
        "Drug": " Canova",
        "Percentile": 57
    },
    {
        "Drug": " Omega-3 fatty acids",
        "Percentile": 43
    },
    {
        "Drug": " Luteolin",
        "Percentile": 29
    },
    {
        "Drug": " Ethanol Extract of Aurantiochytrium sp. (EEA)",
        "Percentile": 14
    }
]
```

and so on, but does not combine the two and does not have the proper labeling such as `"pharmaceuticals": [` and `"nutraceuticals": [` I basically need the two csv file names to be the array titles in the JSON object and then combine the two.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a dictionary object from your two dataframes.

```
d = dict(zip(['Pharmaceuticals','Nutraceuticals'], 
                [Pharmaceuticals,Nutraceuticals]))

out = {k : v.rename(columns={'Drug' : 'name', 'Percentile' : 'percentile'}
        ).to_dict(orient='records')
     for k,v in d.items() }
```

---

```
print(out)

{'Pharmaceuticals': [{'name': 'SZ Antipsychotic', 'percentile': 57},
  {'name': 'AMG 811', 'percentile': 57},
  {'name': 'Colchicine', 'percentile': 57},
  {'name': 'Ibuprofen', 'percentile': 29},
  {'name': 'Sleep Deprivation', 'percentile': 29},
  {'name': 'Rofecoxib', 'percentile': 29}],
 'Nutraceuticals': [{'name': 'Canova', 'percentile': 57},
  {'name': 'Omega-3 fatty acids', 'percentile': 43},
  {'name': 'Luteolin', 'percentile': 29},
  {'name': 'Ethanol Extract of Aurantiochytrium sp. (EEA)', 'percentile': 14},
  {'name': 'Osthole', 'percentile': 14},
  {'name': 'Arisaema amurense var. serratum', 'percentile': 14}]}
```

then dump to json.

```
with open('yourfile.json','w') as fp:
    json.dump(out,fp,indent=4)
```

### `yourfile.json`

```
{
    "Pharmaceuticals": [
        {
            "name": "SZ Antipsychotic",
            "percentile": 57
        },
        {
            "name": "AMG 811",
            "percentile": 57
        },
        {
            "name": "Colchicine",
            "percentile": 57
        },
        {
            "name": "Ibuprofen",
            "percentile": 29
        },
        {
            "name": "Sleep Deprivation",
            "percentile": 29
        },
        {
            "name": "Rofecoxib",
            "percentile": 29
        }
    ],
    "Nutraceuticals": [
        {
            "name": "Canova",
            "percentile": 57
        },
        {
            "name": "Omega-3 fatty acids",
            "percentile": 43
        },
        {
            "name": "Luteolin",
            "percentile": 29
        },
        {
            "name": "Ethanol Extract of Aurantiochytrium sp. (EEA)",
            "percentile": 14
        },
        {
            "name": "Osthole",
            "percentile": 14
        },
        {
            "name": "Arisaema amurense var. serratum",
            "percentile": 14
        }
    ]
}
```